# I exactly will come\ I will exactly come

Tags: adverbs

I got a little stuck with **"exactly"** in the word order:

*Don't doubt about me, I will exactly come to the party!*

Where should I put it? Can it be:

*Don't doubt about me, I **exactly** will come to the party!* ?

Or even at the end:

*Don't doubt about me, I will come to the party **exactly**!* ?

To be on the safe side it's possible to use **"shall"**:

*Don't doubt about me, I **shall** come to the party!*

I'd heard it wasn't used much anymore in the sense of some guarantee, high determination and so on but I got some comment that it was possible and possible with "I, we", too, not only with "you, he, she, it, they". Though it's a different thread.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exactly Your sentences are not grammatical. Please check dictionaries.

Comment: I think those sentences are grammatical, but the word choice isn't as felicitous, rendering them unidiomatic / nonnative / unclear. I think you want *definitely*, and you can sort of put it anywhere: *I'll / I will definitely come...*, *I definitely will come...* (with the emphasis being borne by *will*), *I'll come to the party – definitely*, (as a sort of afterthought, where a dash or some stronger kind of pause indicator is needed, in my opinion).

Comment: "Don't doubt about me" is very strange.

Comment: Is "Don't have nay doubs about me" better?